# Make a datepicker .html() object into a text field, not a span

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need help for the final touch of a jQuery UI customization. I have this jQuery Datepicker that works great... but I need it to do one more thing for me. As is, the output of the .html() comes as **span**. I need **form text fields instead of spans**.

In the example below, I'd want to have the day, month and year to show up as form fields; not as span. I've considered using multiple AltFields, but I couldn't get a respective altFormat for each AltField... So thanks to [Rusln](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2050459/rusln) I made great progress but I couldn't manage to get to achieve the form fields part. See for yourself :

JS:

```
    $(".full_date").datepicker({
    showOn: 'button',
    buttonText: 'Here',
    dateFormat: 'DD, dd MM yy',
    altFormat: "yy-mm",
    altField: ".year-month",
    onClose: function (dateText, picker) {
        // getDate returns a js Date object
         var dateObject = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
        console.dir(dateObject);
        // Call Date object methods
        $("#date span").html(dateObject.getDate());
        $("#month span").html(dateObject.getMonth());
        $("#day span").html(dateObject.getDay());
        $("#year span").html(dateObject.getFullYear());
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
    <h1>Date Picker</h1>

<form class="date-picker">
    <label>full date</label>
    <input type="text" class="full_date" value="" />
        <label>year month</label>
    <input type="text" class="year-month"/>
</form>
<p id="day">Day of the week: <span></span> </p>
<p id="month">Month: <span></span></p>
<p id="date">Date: <span></span></p>
<p id="year">Year: <span></span></p>
```

I looked at this quite a bit but with no luck so far... I feel like I've browsed all the jQuery documentation a couple of times. Can someone please point out some references so I can get that example to work ?

See the [EXAMPLE ON JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/toutgreg/MP98F/)

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just turn then into input fields and use **[val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** instead of .html()

#### Markup

```
<p id="day">Day of the week: <input name="day" type="text"></input> </p>
<p id="month">Month: <input name="month" type="text"></input></p>
<p id="date">Date: <input name="date" type="text"></input></p>
<p id="year">Year: <input name="year" type="text"></input></p>
```

#### Script

```
$(".full_date").datepicker({
    showOn: 'button',
    buttonText: 'Here',
    dateFormat: 'DD, dd MM yy',
    altFormat: "yy-mm",
    altField: ".year-month",
    onClose: function (dateText, picker) {
        // getDate returns a js Date object
         var dateObject = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
        console.dir(dateObject);
        // Call Date object methods
        $("#date input").val(dateObject.getDate());
        $("#month input").val(dateObject.getMonth());
        $("#day input").val(dateObject.getDay());
        $("#year input").val(dateObject.getFullYear());
    }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gNu8p/)**

Comment: I would hug you so strong if you were in this room with me. THANK YOU PSL.